# Problemas no comando select do linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-core, asp, linq-to-entities

A query funcionou ela tem 2 perguntas de forma randomica com as 5 opções cada uma.
O problema é que o meu select carrega a view descrita abaixo:

````cs
 public class QuestaoOpcaoModel
    {
        public int QuestaoId { get; set; }
        public string QuestaoPergunta { get; set; }
        public int OpcaoId { get; set; }
        public string OpcaoDescricao { get; set; }
    }

Aí tentei o seguinte código:
```c#
(from q in _educ365Context.Questoes
                 join op in _educ365Context.Opcoes on q.Id equals op.QuestaoId
                 where q.TemaId == int.Parse(tema)
                 orderby rnd.Next()
                 select new QuestaoOpcaoModel
                 {
                     QuestaoId = q.Id,
                     QuestaoPergunta = q.Pergunta,
                     OpcaoId = op.Id,
                     OpcaoDescricao = op.opcaoResposta
                 })
                .Take(2);
E ao fazer isso me trouxe as 2 perguntas mas com apenas 1 opção sendo que e, cada pergunta existem 5 opções vinculas a ela. Como posso fazer para resolver isso?
````

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema, eu apenas desmembrei a minha consulta em duas. A primeira para pegar as perguntas de forma randômica:

```cs
var questions = (from q in db.Questoes where q.TemaId == int.Parse(tema) orderby rnd.Next() select q).Take(2);
```

A segunda faz um join da primeira com a tabela de opções relacionadas:

```cs
prova = (from q in questions
                            join op in db.Opcoes on q.Id equals op.QuestaoId
                            select new QuestaoOpcaoModel
                            {
                                QuestaoId = q.Id,
                                QuestaoPergunta = q.Pergunta,
                                OpcaoId = op.Id,
                                OpcaoDescricao = op.opcaoResposta
                            }).AsQueryable();
```

E com isso funcionou. Nenhuma opção foi da minha model QuestaoOpcaoModel foi perdida. Mas se tiverem alguma opinião para tornar mais fácil, não deixem de enviar

Comment: Boa Marcelo, ainda bem que conseguiu!